# How to compute the optimal ridge regression model

Tags: matlab, regression

I found R function [ridge.cv](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=parcor%3aridge.cvunction) very useful.

I would like to implement the equivalent function in MATLAB. As a starting point, I used MATLAB function `b0 = ridge(y,X,k,scale)`, however it gives completely different results. Why does this might happen? What value should I set for variable "scale" (1 or 0 and what's their difference?)? And how could I implement it from the scratch in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

One form of ridge regression is the problem:
     minimize |Ax - b|, and keep x near a given point x0 (often 0).
If we cast this as:
     minimize |Ax - b|^2 + w^2 |x - x0|^2 ,
we can solve it by running least squares on these extended inputs:

```
[ A ]    [ b ]
[ w I ]  [ w x0 ]
```

Here w is a weight factor that balances minimizing |Ax - b|, and keeping x near x0.
How should one choose it if one has no idea ?
A rule of thumb is to make |Ax - b| and |x - x0| roughly equal -- print those values.

Added:
[Weighted least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares),
with different weights w$_i$, is a powerful method.
For example, w$_i \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt |\text{x}_i|}$
pushes small x$_i$ towards 0 (think iPhone fingers), "sparsifies" —
a poor man's approach to L1-norm regularization;
see [LASSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_%28statistics%29#LASSO_method).

Not Matlab, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the source and documentation for the [parcor package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/parcor/index.html) which includes the  ridge.cv function on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/parcor/index.html).

You can implement the function in matlab by looking at the source. Alternatively, I think it should be possible to call R from Matlab.